# How do I mail a postcard?

Tags: pikuniku

In [Pikuniku](https://pikuniku.net/) a friendly ghost asked me to send a postcard once in a while.

I've now found a postcard, and I've noticed various postboxes around the world.

[image]

But I can't for the life of me figure out how to put the card in the box. *Someone please explain this to me.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The developers said on twitter that [*"You can’t send the postcards."*](https://twitter.com/PikuNikuGame/status/1090263140133007360)

Answer (score 0):

found your question while searching for the answer myself. Found them on Twitter saying you can't send the postcards. We cannot be nice to ghost. :,<

Comment: Can you link to the source?

Comment: Sourced below   vvv